# Posterior predictive density with latent variables in STAN

Tags: bayesian, stan

Using STAN, how do one calculate the posterior predictive density in a model with latent variables in a specified point.

As an example consider a model with a single random effect:

$
Y_{ij} = a\delta_i + b\epsilon_{ij}\qquad i=1,\ldots N,\quad j=1,\ldots K
$

where $\delta_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. The model has two parameters $\theta=(a,b)$. We can build the model in STAN with flat priors

```
data {
  int N;
  int K;
  real y[N,K];
}

parameters {
  real<lower=0> a;
  real<lower=0> b;
  real delta[N];
}

model {
  for ( n in 1:N){
    delta[n] ~ normal(0, a);
    y[n] ~ normal(delta[n], b);
  }
}
```

Now given a new data point $Y = (Y_1,\ldots Y_K)$, we want to compute the posterior predictive density

$
p_{\text{post}}(Y) = \int p(y|\theta)p_{\text{post}}(\theta) \,\text{d}\theta
$

We could use the "generated quantities" block in STAN and compute $P(Y|a,b)$, this however requires us to integrate out $\delta$, i.e.

$
p(Y|a,b) = \int p(Y|a,b,\delta)p(\delta|a,b) \,\text{d}\delta
$

For this particular model this integration yields a closed-form expression, but for more complex models this is not the case.

Is there some general scheme that can be exploited in the STAN framework to obtain this posterior density? I have considered numerical integration but I think that it will require a large amount of model specific effort. Naive Monte Carlo integration can easily fail if $p(Y|a,b,\delta)$ is large in regions where $p(\delta|a,b)$ is small.

Comment: Is the intent of the question to indeed ask about somehow evaluating/approximating the density, i.e., samples from the posterior predictive distribution are not enough?

Comment: Are you asking for code? If so, that would be off topic here.

Comment: @Juho No I'm trying to get at the density at specific points - I need it to do cross validation.

Comment: @Gung I'm looking for a statistical method rather than code. I believe that it should somehow be possible to do clever Monte Carlo integration to get at \int p(Y|a,b,\delta)p(\delta|a,b) d\delta.

Comment: Have you tried asking on the Stan users [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/stan-users/general)?